# Is there a way to automatically download all the packages(and the correct versions) needed to run the code in github repo that I've cloned?

Tags: git, github, command-line, package, conda

Looking to run someone else's code from a Github repo that i've cloned onto my local machine.

Quite a few packages and I was wondering if there was a way to 'automatically' (or at most using a few lines in terminal) set up my conda environment so that I can run the files without having to manually go and download each package?

Comment: If they have a requirements.txt or environment yml file then yes. Otherwise, I don't think there is any generalized way. Inlcuding the link to the github might help

Answer (score 1):

I assume this code is in python. If so, then if they have a requirements.txt file you can run pip install -r requirements.txt to install them all. If not you will manually have to pip install each one.

Answer (score 0):

If the repo is having a file called package.json. then use the command npm install. this command will automatically install all the packages mentioned in the package.json file

Comment: I expect this is a good answer if the project is in JavaScript or related, but OP talks about conda, so they're probably working with a Python project.